# Activating Proxy service consumer from ABAP

Tags: web-services, proxy, abap, consumer

I've just created a service consumer and generated its code from ABAP in order to send to the target WSDL system XML file which is created successfully.
The code should fill in the XML_FILE_INFO fields but have no idea if I did it OK:

[image: Service consumer]

The code to activate it:

```
  " Call method, and receive a response
  try.
    lo_proxy->SET_MESSAGE(
      exporting
        INPUT  = gs_input
      importing
        OUTPUT = ls_output
    ).
    catch CX_AI_SYSTEM_FAULT INTO lo_AI_SYSTEM_FAULT. "lo_ai_system_fault_info.
    catch CX_AI_APPLICATION_FAULT INTO LO_AI_APPLICATION_FAULT.
  ENDTRY.
```

How should I fill the XML file's content in the GS_INPUT structure? IS putting the file's path in the FILE_NAME field enough?

If someone had already done something like the mentioned requirement I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't know the web service you are using. Please refer to its documentation. But it's non-sense to pass the file's path. By looking at the web service field names, I feel that FileBuffer is the place to pass the file content, maybe it's to be encoded in base 64 (whatever the file is text or bytes). If it's a text file, then you have to indicate the encoding (maybe the names defined by IANA). Of course, indicate a file name WITHOUT the path (and a file extension if applicable).

Comment: Give us the WSDL of your service